# Embedding a semigroup into a monoid

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, monoid

I have just started learning about groups and rings and I'm stuck on one exercise. I don't understand what $S^u$ really is and don't know where to start. So if anybody could help me with it, it would be amazing.

The exercise is the following:

Let $S$ be a semigroup, and let $u$ be an element such that $u \notin S$. On the disjoint union $S \sqcup\{u\}$ we define a binary operation $$\cdot \colon (S \sqcup\{u\}) \times(S \sqcup\{u\}) \rightarrow(S \sqcup\{u\})$$ given by:
$$ \left \{
\begin{array}[cc]
ss \cdot t=s t & \text{if } s, t \in S , \\
s \cdot u=u \cdot s=s &  \text{if } s \in S, \\
u \cdot u=u &
\end{array}
\right. $$
The resulting semigroup $S^{u}$ is a monoid. We define the unitization $\hat{S}$ of $S$ as
$$\hat{S}= \left \{
\begin{array}[cc]
SS & \text{if } S \text{ is a monoid} \\
S^{u} & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right. $$

Prove that if $M$ is a monoid and $\alpha: S \rightarrow M$ is a homomorphism, there exists a unique homomorphism of monoids $\hat{\alpha}: \hat{S} \rightarrow M$ such that $\hat{\alpha}(x)=\alpha(x)$ if $x \in S$.

Comment: The monoid $S^u$ makes sense even if $S$ is already a monoid.

Comment: $S^u$ is just the pair $(S \sqcup \{u\},\cdot)$, which happens to be a semigroup (check that $\cdot$ is associative, and clearly $u$ is a unit).

Comment: Notice that $S^u$ can be divided into two sets $S$ and $\{u\}$. You know that $\hat\alpha(x)$ must be equal to $\alpha(x)$, for all $x\in S$, so you know how $\hat\alpha$ behaves on $S$. For the condition that $\hat\alpha$ is a homomorphism of monoids, you know that $\hat\alpha(u)=\dots$ can you continue from here? $S^u$ is just the answer to the question "what is the least monoid containing a semigroup $S$?", simply $S$ together with an identity $u$, so $S^u=S\sqcup\{u\}$

Answer (score 0):

If $S$ is a monoid, then $\hat S = S$ and $\hat \alpha = \alpha$. Otherwise, $\hat S = S^u$. Let $1$ be the identity of $M$. If $\hat \alpha$ exists, it is necessarily defined by
$$
(*) \quad \hat \alpha(s) = \begin{cases}
\alpha(s) &\text{if $s \in S\quad$ (by definition)} \\ 
1 &\text{if $s = u\quad$ (by definition of a homomorphism of monoids)}
\end{cases}
$$
This proves unicity. It remains to prove that $(*)$ defines a homomorphism of monoids. Let $s, t \in S^u$. Then
$$
\hat\alpha(s)\hat\alpha(t) = \begin{cases}
\alpha(s)\alpha(t) = \alpha(st) = \hat\alpha(st) &\text{if $s,t \in S$}\\
\alpha(s)1 = \alpha(s) = \alpha(su) = \hat\alpha(st) &\text{if $s \in S$ and $t=u$}\\
1\alpha(t) = \alpha(t) = \alpha(ut) = \hat\alpha(st)
&\text{if $s = u$ and $t \in S$}\\
1 = \hat\alpha(st) & \text{if $s = t = u$}\end{cases}
$$
and thus $\hat \alpha(s)\hat\alpha(t) = \hat\alpha(st)$ in all cases. Moreover $\hat\alpha(u) = 1$ by definition.